# Hide images completely using the <picture> element

Tags: html, css, image

Just wondering if anyone knows a way to hide images in the `<picture>` elements for certain widths, rather than replacing them with another image.

Previously I was showing/hiding images using @media queries in my custom CSS, but was recently made aware of the `<picture>` element to place images to show at specific widths.

This has been a much easier way to show different images for mobile vs desktop for images that sit in the same place on both versions (for example between two paragraphs of text).

But I've got some images that will sit a bit higher up on desktop than mobile though, for example an image I want to the right of a piece of text is placed at the start of that paragraph, but on mobile I want the image to appear after the paragraph.

For example the first image in my post here advertising my 30 Day Challenge: http://www.smartfertilitychoices.com/pcos-diet-plan/
(Still using the @media queries for this post)

Is it possible to hide/show images altogether for certain widths using the `<picture>` element?

I hope this makes sense, and thanks in advance!

Comment: I would recommand checking out bootstrap

Comment: Just use @media queries and set `display: none` on the `<picture>` elements once a certain criteria is met.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Simply use a bootstrap class.
You can choose below depends on the width size you want

```
<div class = "hidden-xs "></div>
<div class = "hidden-sm "></div>
<div class = "hidden-md "></div>
<div class = "hidden-lg "></div>
```

For Reference:[image]

But if you rally want to set it in a very certain specific width, then just use media queries.

Want to know more about Bootstrap? Then check this out: 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/

Answer (score 1):

```
<picture>
<source media="(min-width: 1280px)" srcset="Enter your image(1) URL (or) Image(1) Path">
<source media="(min-width: 480px)" srcset="Enter your image(2) URL  (or) Image(2) Path">
<img src="Enter your image(3) URL  (or) Image(3) Path" alt="Image(3)" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

Resize the browser to see different versions of the picture loading at different viewport sizes.

The **picture** element is not supported in IE12 and earlier or Safari 9.0 and earlier.